# Declare a Public array that stores strings and can be accessed from different functions in VBA

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel, powerpoint

I need to have a common array in which a list of strings have to be stored, with provision to add new strings and access existing strings inside it from any part of my project in VBA.

Basically, I should have a array of WordstobeIgnored. I should be able to add new words inside this. And access all the words inside this so that I can call it and use it in different parts of the project.

I've tried declaring variants in Public and storing string data inside it. Didn't help. Wasn't able to declare a dynamic array of string in public too. Need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it at the top of you form or module code.

```
Option Explicit
Public strValues() As String


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End sub

Private sub SettingValue() as string

End sub
```

Or depending on the scope of what you are doing, create a module called globals and declare it there.

Comment: If declared as string in public, Can I add new values into the string from anywhere in the project? And don't I have to declare the size of the string? Is it dynamic?

Comment: It all depends on the scope of what your are doing. If you declare it public in form1, you can access it from another form by referring to it as form1.strValues.  You can declare the size if you would like there are several ways to use arrays.  You can always redim also.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. I need a public array of strings. I should be able to add more strings into it from a function. And access the data into the array using another function for a different purpose. I don't have confusions about the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code on the top of any module:

```
Public WordsToBeIgnored() As String
```

It will declare public variable `WordsToBeIgnored` accessible from everywhere in this VBA project.

However, I think using **Dictionary** instead of array is more suitable for the purpose you described - searching through dictionary in order to check if a value exists is much more efficient than searching through an array.
With dictionary you can do it with one command - `Dict.Exists(key)`, while for arrays you need to iterate through all the items from this array.

Comment: Can you show me a small example code with dictionary? I'm a newbie to this

If declared as string in public, Can I add new values into the string from anywhere in the project? And don't I have to declare the size of the string? Is it dynamic?

Comment: Here is article introducing to dictionaries in VBA: http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html

Comment: I tried the code from the page. And in the part where it says "Set dict = New Dictionary" I get an error saying "Invalid use of New keyword". Can you help me with a working code for this?

Comment: You can use `Set dict = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` instead.

Comment: After this when I try "Dict.Add ***", The reference ".add" is actually not available in the list. I've enabled the scripting reference in Tools -> References

Comment: Have you declared variable `Dict` as `Scripting.Dictionary` type?